# Why does the race detector report a race condition, here?

Tags: go, synchronization, global-variables, mutex, race-condition

I am using Go race detection (the -race argument), and it detects some race conditions issues that I think should not be reported. I've created this sample code to explain my findings. Please do not comment about the goal of this example, as it has no goal other than to explain the issue.

This code:

```
var count int

func main() {
    go update()
    for {
        fmt.Println(count)
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}

func update() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        count++
    }
}
```

is reported with a race condition.

While this code:

```
var count int
var mutex sync.RWMutex

func main() {
    go update()
    for {
        mutex.RLock()
        fmt.Println(count)
        mutex.RUnlock()
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}

func update(){
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        mutex.Lock()
        count++
        mutex.Unlock()
    }
}
```

is not reported with any race condition issues.

My question is why?
There no bug in the first code.
The main function is reading a variable that another go routine is updating.
There is no potential hidden bug here.
The second code mutex does not provide any different behavior.

Where am I wrong here?

Comment: "it detects some race conditions issues that I think should not be reported"  -- The race detector only reports actual, observed races. It does not have false positives. It can have false negatives (that is, there can be races it doesn't detect, if the race isn't triggered during a particular run)

Comment: I am not referring to false negative. I am referring to a false positive.

Comment: I realize that. I'm explaining: There are no false positives.

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem in the first code. Where is the bug?

Comment: The bug is in that `count` is read and written at the same time from different goroutines.

Comment: @alonana 2 threads/goroutines which access the same memory address and at least one modifies it === data race, by definition.

Comment: Sorry for nagging about this. I truly want to understand this issue. Why is this a bug? I will get the same incrementing value in the main regardless of using a mutex. The behavior is as expected in the first case as in the second case.

Comment: The bug is that when you write to a variable at the same time you read from it, the result is undefined.  You might read the old value. You might read the new value. You might read a corrupted value. The program might crash. The sky might turn purple and melt into a thousand shards of glass.

Comment: "Why is this a bug?" --- the language memory model explicitly states it as a bug. So it's a bug because the specification says so.

Comment: Go memory model is based on the [C memory model](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/memory_model), in which concurrent read/write of the same memory location is a data race (undefined behavior).

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding for my questions, I really appreciate it. If I read the variable and at the same time write the variable, I might get the old value, and I might get the new value. I totally agree. Still this is not a bug, but an expected behavior. I might get the old value or the new value even when using a mutex. Is it possible to get a corrupted value in case of an int variable? Is it really possible that the program would crash?

Comment: @alonana "but an expected behavior" --- it's not expected, the language memory model cannot predict/guarantee the result. Just because it matches your expectations means nothing.

Comment: a must read https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/blogs/benign-data-races-what-could-possibly-go-wrong.html

Comment: There seems to be a debate of definitions going on here, as well. The OP apparently "wants" undefined behavior. In that sense, a race may not be a bug, strictly speaking. In the same way that I may write a bit of code that's intended to panic, in such a case, a panic is not a "bug" per se.  But outside of test suites, I cannot imagine a legitimate case where one would _want_ to trigger a race, an unknown runtime condition, or a panic.

Comment: You can get a value that is **neither the old value nor the new value**. I can show examples of where this occurs on x86 CPUs (it's a bit tricky, and using a LOCK prefix doesn't fix it!).

Answer (score 4):

Your code contains a very clear race.

Your for loop is accessing `count` at the same time that the other goroutine is updating it. That's the definition of a race.

> The main function is reading a variable that another go routine is updating.

Yes, exactly. That's what a race is.

> The second code mutex does not provide any different behavior.

Yes, it does. It prevents the variable from being read and written at the same time from different goroutines.

Answer (score 2):

You need to draw [a distinction between a *synchronization bug* and a *data race*](https://medium.com/@val_deleplace/does-the-race-detector-catch-all-data-races-1afed51d57fb). A synchronization bug is a property of the code, whereas a data race is a property of a particular execution of the program. The latter is a manifestation of the former, but is in general not guaranteed to occur.

> There no bug in the first code. The main function is reading a variable that another go routine is updating. There is no potential hidden bug here.

The race detector only detects data races, not synchronization bugs. It may miss some data races (false negatives), but [it never reports false positives](https://blog.golang.org/race-detector#TOC_5.):

> The race detector is a powerful tool for checking the correctness of concurrent programs. **It will not issue false positives, so take its warnings seriously.**

In other words, when the race detector reports a data race, you can be sure that your code contains at least one synchronization bug. You need to fix such bugs; otherwise, all bets are off.

Lo and behold, your first code snippet does indeed contain a synchronization bug: package-level variable `count` is accessed (by `main`) and updated (by `update`, started as a goroutine) concurrently without any synchronization. Here is a relevant passage of the [Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem#tmp_1):

> Programs that modify data being simultaneously accessed by multiple goroutines must serialize such access.
> To serialize access, protect the data with channel operations or other synchronization primitives such as those in the `sync` and `sync/atomic` packages.

Using a reader/writer mutual-exclusion lock, as you did in your second snippet, fixes your synchronization bug.

> The second code mutex does not provide any different behavior.

You just got lucky, when you executed the first program, that no data race occurred. In general, you have no guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

This is off topic for Go (and the sample Go code won't trigger the problem even on x86 CPUs), but I have a demonstration proof, from roughly a decade ago at this point, that "torn reads" can produce inconsistent values even if the read and write operations are done with LOCK CMPXCHG8B, on some x86 CPUs (I think we were using early Haswell implementations).

The particular conditions that trigger this are a little difficult to set up.  We had a custom allocator that had a bug: it only did four-byte alignment.<sup>1</sup>  We then had a "lock-free" (single locking instruction) algorithm to add entries to a queue, with single-writer multi-reader semantics.

It turns out that LOCK CMPXCHG8B instructions "work" on misaligned pointers as long as they do not cross page boundaries.  As soon as they do, though, the *readers* can see a torn read, in which they get half the old value and half the new value, when a writer is doing an atomic write.

The result was an extremely difficult-to-track-down bug, where the system would run well for hours or even days before tripping over one of these.  I finally diagnosed it by observing the data patterns, and eventually tracked the problem down to the allocator.

---

<sup>1</sup>Whether this *is* a bug depends on how one uses the allocated objects, but we were using them as 8-byte-wide pointers with LOCK CMPXCHG8B instructions.

Comment: "won't trigger the problem even on x86 CPUs" --- what prevents a Go compiler to optimise reading a variable in `fmt.Println(count)` to `fmt.Println(0)`? Or if not to a constant but to move loading the value to be done once right before the loop?

Comment: @zerkms: What I mean is, the given Go code won't compile to LOCK CMPXCHG8B instructions that operate on a four-byte aligned pointer that straddles a page boundary. :-) (Oddly, it seemed to work on ones that straddled *cache-line* boundaries.) A torn read could still happen in some cases, but the compiler won't generate one here. The real point of the anecdote, in any case, is to show that surprises happen: you need to rely on *promised* behavior.